# Создание своей команды для командной строки windows

Tags: windows, cmd

Я часто использую командную строку, и почти каждый раз начинаю свои работу с перехода в папку с проектами. Это не очень удобно, можно ли как-то сделать свою команду которая будет переносить меня сразу в нужную папку?

Comment: `cd path\to\project`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Зайдите в любую директорию, которая установлена как `Path` (Панель управления - Система - Дополнительные параметры системы - Параметры среды... - Path).
  Одной из таких директорий является `C:\Windows\System32`.
- В данную директорию поместите/создайте файл с расширением `.cmd`/`.bat`, имя данного файла будет являться будущей командой.
- Пропишите в данном файле все, что вам необходимо, например задать директорию:

  ```
  @ECHO OFF
  cd /D D:\Downloads
  ```

Все, можем проверять новую команду: Открываем консоль и пишем `имя файла` (у меня файл `.test.cmd` и по этому я пишу `test`).

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:
Можно в отдельной папке, например (Z:\scripts), создать .bat скрипт, назвать его например project.bat и наполнить его содержимым:

```
cd path\to\project
```

После чего, нужно добавить путь Z:\scripts в переменную PATH в настройках переменных сред.
И при вызове project в консоли, будет исполнятся содержимое файла project.bat

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто в папку с **cmd** закинуть файл с командой, он также будет работать где угодно при любом запуске. Таким образом в **cmd** можно добавить сколько угодно команд.

Переходим в папку **C:\Windows\System32** и называем файл так, как будем использовать команду, например **projects**. В нём нам надо будет написать слудующее:

```
@echo off
cd /d путь до твоей папки
```

Теперь когда ты будешь писать **projects** в **cmd**, тебя будет перенаправлять в папку. Ещё для удобства можно добавить команду:

```
start твоя папка
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать файл [ваша_команда].bat с форматом bat или cmd. Дальше напишите внутрь:

```
@echo off
[и пишите сюда, что будет выполнять команда]
```

Дальше перейдите по пути C:\Windows\System32 и перекиньте туда этот файл. Откройте командную строку и напишите название файла которого вы перекинули в C:\Windows\System32

Всё.

Answer (score 0):

Скопируй батник в папку System32 и будет тебе команда